# matlab - changing values of a global variable via command window

Tags: matlab, global-variables

Suppose you had a global variable G in a function f, say.
The output of f is dependent on G, and G is declared to be global within f.

I would like f to work as follows through the command window:

- set G to some value
- run f, giving some result dependent on G
- set a different value of G
- run f again, giving an answer dependent on the new G

However, this has the following problem:
it would involve defining G first, then declaring it to be global when f is run, which results in a matlab warning
I would also require that the global variable G is not a direct input for f.

Any help to work around this, or if my method is fundamentally flawed, an alternative would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the problem. If `G` is declared as `global` within `f`, you can declare `G` as `global` in Matlab, then define its value and then call `f`, without any warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. A simple example:

In the command window, enter `global G` and `G=2`.

Then make a simple function, e.g.:

```
function incG
global G
G=G*2;
disp(G)
```

Run `incG` from the command window and see what happens. You can also modify the value of `G` in the command window in between executing `incG`. You do have to be careful that `G` exists and has the correct value when you run `incG`.